# understanding new keyword association to jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How should I define whats going on here from left to right. I'm perplexed with the **[0].nameofsomething** part.  Stupid quesiton for bonus, can the [0] be any other integer too?  It looks like the jquery selector is now namespaced..is that correct?

```
$("#someselector")[0].nameofsomething = new MyObject();
```

and could this also be written like this....

```
$("#someselector").nameofsomething = new MyObject();
```

and produce exactly the same results?

thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [0] selects the DOM object, so you are adding to the element.

```
$("#someselector")[0].nameofsomething  // this is same thing as document.getElementById("someselector").nameofsomething = {};
```

You are adding to the jQuery object

```
$("#someselector").nameofsomething
```

So they are not the same thing.

Comment: thank you epascarello for the quick answer.  I have one more imbarrasing question to ask to my main one.  Why would people need to get the "raw" DOM by the use of [0], rather than just depending on a jquery selector name???  I guess I'm new to understanding the logic behind that motive... thanks!

Comment: There is no reason why. People might not know how to get something in jQuery so they use the DOM. Some people want to integrate with non jquery code and use the DOM to pass to another script. They might want to interact with the element without using jQuery. Sometimes it is for speed, sometimes it for lack of knowledge, sometimes it is just easier.

Comment: If you want to select an element and keep it as jQuery use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).